# Are there any apps that will post to multiple social networking accounts at once?

Tags: software-rec, web

I currently use [Ping.fm](http://ping.fm) to post to multiple social networks at once, but it's been irritating me for a while and I'm thinking of writing a tool to replace it for myself. But I figure it's possible that someone has already done that. To be a suitable replacement it needs to handle twitter, and facebook; myspace, linkedin, and google buzz are a bonus, of course everything else is frosting. In addition to allowing *me* to send messages it must also be able to read multiple rss feeds and aggregate them to the networks I set up. If 2 or more tools, in conjunction can be made to do this that is also acceptable, e.g. `feedreader | cleanupforstream | post2stream`.

If it doesn't exist I think I'll just write some Perl to do it for me, and put it on CPAN.

Answer (score 4):

[Gwibber](http://gwibber.com/) has the ability to send to multiple services at once.  According to their website it supports the following protocols/services:

- Twitter
- Identi.ca/StatusNet
- Ping.fm
- Facebook
- FriendFeed
- Buzz
- Digg
- Flickr
- Qaiku

As far as I know, it has the ability to receive content from all of the listed services, but I'm not sure if there is a way to receive arbitrary RSS feeds.

Comment: ugh... it pulls in gnome.... that's just probably not going to work for me probably.

Comment: "ugh" indeed. I see no reason for this to pull in gnome considering the requirements listed here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gwibber-committers/gwibber/trunk/view/head:/INSTALL

Comment: well I'm much too lazy to figure out which dep on arch pulls in a large chunk of gnome, esp when I run kde